# What is this grey theme seen on the gooseberry website?

Tags: interface, theme

This link is from the goosebery project site: http://gooseberry.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/By4XQI3CEAEZUZ4.png

[image]

Any ideas of what UI theme is this?

Comment: That looks like the Mac OS X theme that [Mike Pan created](https://twitter.com/themikepan/status/517022204106903552).

Comment: Not quite :) But thanks for the mention anyway!

Comment: It may not even be a 'theme' in the sense that it has been uploaded and is being distributed.  Anyone can alter how their UI looks by using the Themes tab in User Preferences.  That could just be personal user settings.

Comment: I think it could be the [flatty light theme](https://developer.blender.org/T43347), which was [added to master](https://developer.blender.org/rB87fb7ee7e9d4bcec477d7960b552b48fbf0462b8) recently.